# How to query elasticsearch on apache drill

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, apache-drill

I execute query sql in es:

```
select * from es_index;
```

and receive a response:

```
Couldn't get indices
```

Can anyone give some solution?Thanks.

Comment: Why you are using SQL query with elastic search ? There is API for it

Comment: yes. apache drill version 1.19 support elasticsearch sources

Comment: While you can query elasticsearch with SQL, you can't join external sources.  Drill lets you query multiple disparate sources using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug with getting the indexes from ElasticSearch and Drill 1.19. This has been fixed and the fix will be in Drill 1.20.0 which will be released before the end of the year.

In the meantime, you can d/l and build the most current master and it should work.

**UPDATE**:  Drill 1.20 has been released.  Please use that to query ElasticSearch.